# Meteor method does not return when passing a value

Tags: meteor

I am trying to pass a value in the callback of an async meteor method. "mongoCollections" is global variable

```
// Async method
let waiter = function(cb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(undefined, {data: 'test', other: mongoCollections}) 
    }, 1000);
}

// Meteor method
Meteor.methods({
    'getCollections': () => {
        let func = Meteor.wrapAsync(waiter);
        let res = func();
        return res;
    }
});
```

On the client

```
Meteor.call('getCollections', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res)
});
```

The issue is that in its current state the client callback is not fired, no error or anything.

But if I remove the "other: mongoCollections" part of the object then the callback is fired. Why would sending mongoCollections prevent the callback from being fired at all? If there is an error how can I catch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are loosing your context between `waiter()` and the execution of `cb()`, which means that `mongoCollections` is undefined in `cb()`, thus the call fails.

Try to log `mongoCollections` in the anonymous function that you `setTimeout` for. It will probably show as `undefined`.

Or try it like this:

```
let waiter = function(cb) {
    var _mongoCollections = mongoCollections;
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(undefined, {data: 'test', other: _mongoCollections}) 
    }, 1000);
}
```

(which puts mongoCollections in the closure instsead)

Another possibility (based on comment below): Your mongoCollections object is not serializable. You can try it by logging the result of `JSON.stringify(mongoCollections)`. If this fails you have to extract the parts of the object you need, that **can** be serialized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, "mongoCollections" is logging correctly in terminal when running console.log(mongoCollections) within the setTimeout callback. Actually when I send back "other: typeof _mongoCollections" the client does log "object" which is correct, but removing "typeof" again stops the callback from executing at all.

Comment: ...which leads to an alternative possibility. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be happening here, but my guess is that an error is occurring somewhere and the error message is getting swallowed by a handler somewhere deeper.

You probably want to be using `Meteor.setTimeout` instead of vanilla `setTimeout` at a minimum.  Have a look here: http://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setTimeout

Beyond that, I would follow the previous answerer's advice and try to make sure that mongoCollections is as global as you think it is.  If the only change between the callback working and not working is the addition of a single symbol, then the culprit is likely that your added symbol is undefined.